# Finding All Divisors Of A Prime Number

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Let $p$ be a prime number, Find all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ s.t $x\mid p$

By definition the divisors of $p$ are $\pm1$ and $\pm p$ am I done? I mean can I use the definition and the question is trivial, or should I use $\gcd$ or other properties?

Comment: It depends where $p$ is. Is $p \in \Bbb Z$?

Comment: It is not given, just that it is a prime

Comment: Well, it may be **the definition** of "prime number" is such that it makes this question non-trivial. For example, you could be given the definition $\;p\in\Bbb Z\;$ is prime if for $\;a,b\in\Bbb Z,\,p\,\mid\,ab\iff p\,\mid\,a\;\;\text{or}\;\;p\,\mid\,b\;$ .

Comment: Without further context, it should be a (positive) integer prime number. But in fact, this question would be rather boring in this case.

Comment: I suspect that your exercise assumes $p$ is a prime integer, and that we are looking for integer divisors of $p$.  But we are not happy to hear "It is not given, just that it is a prime."  You are implying that your role is merely to pass along your assignment without taking responsibility for being the one who asks or for recalling the context of the problem.

Comment: @hardmath Sorry if that what you inferred from my comment, I have solve the qeustion, but it was rather trivial, so I wanted to be sure that I am not missing something. Therefore I answered the in the question it was not written any further information on $p$, just that it is a prime

Comment: @gbox I think it is not acceptable to receive a question that the asker cannot explain, meaning: it is the responsibility of the asker to clear out, with his book, instructor, teacher, etc., any obscure elements in the question, as we (this site's members) cannot guess (though sometimes we really try hard...) what **exactly** is the asker's background, what class was the question taken from, etc.

Comment: @DonAntonio I Totally agree, I must say that I am so thankful to you guys, I learn a lot, also from those comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you KNOW that $p$ is prime (or if you assume it), you , of course can use this property to prove that there are only $4$ divisors.

Comment: Small thing I notice now, when we say $n\mid m$ we can say that $m=kn$ where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ but we can not say that of $1\mid p$ then $p=k*1$ where $p$ is prime and $k\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @gbox Why we cannot say what you say we can't? You lost me...

Comment: @DonAntonio I will phrase it as a question does $1\mid p \iff p=k*1$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @gbox And the answer to that question is: yes, of course! In this case, $\;p\;$ can be **any** integer and thus $\;k=p\;$, of course.